# Array of array of strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

In C, in a array that looks something like

```
{{"gsga","baf"},{"ad","aasb","asdf","asdfsd"},{"ads","sd","sd"}}
```

How to get different types of lengths such as:

- to get the total size of array (in this example it is 3 because it
  contains 3 arrays of strings)
- how to get size of any array within this array (for example size of
  2nd array of this array is 4 since the second array contains 4
  elements namely `"ad","aasb","asdf","asdfsd"`
- how to get size of individual strings of any array (for example the
  size of 2nd string of 2nd array (i.e. `"aasb"`) is 5).

Comment: What have you tried/researched? There are answers to all three of your examples on Stack Overflow already.

Comment: When dealing with ragged arrays, a common idiom is a [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value).

Comment: "how to get size of individual strings" You probably know that you can get the length of strings with `strlen`, which requires the strings to be null-terminated. It is not quite clear what you need your arrays for, but you could terminate your other arrays with `NULL`, too and implement a length function similar to `strlen`. (Of course, the terminator would then be a null pointer, not a null char.)

Comment: In short you can't get size of an array in C. For size of string, use strlen

Comment: Are you operating on the array of strings within the **same scope** where the array was declared? And is it an array, or are we talking about *pointer-to-pointer-to-char*??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the size of all dimensions (3 x 4 x 7) using the `sizeof` operator.

If you want to know the length of the last one, use `strlen` in a loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char data[][4][7] = {{"gsga","baf"},{"ad","aasb","asdf","asdfsd"},{"ads","sd","sd"}};
    size_t items1 = sizeof data / sizeof data[0]; /* size of dim 1 */
    size_t items2 = sizeof data[0] / sizeof data[0][0]; /* size of dim 2 */
    size_t iter1, iter2, count, len;

    printf("%zu items\n", items1);
    for (iter1 = 0; iter1 < items1; iter1++) {
        count = 0;
        printf("Item %zu\n", iter1);
        for (iter2 = 0; iter2 < items2; iter2++) {
            len = strlen(data[iter1][iter2]); /* size of dim 3 */
            if (len > 0) {
                printf("\tSubitem %zu: %zu characters\n", iter2, len);
                count++;
            }
        }
        printf("\t%zu subitems\n", count);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3 items
Item 0
    Subitem 0: 4 characters
    Subitem 1: 3 characters
    2 subitems
Item 1
    Subitem 0: 2 characters
    Subitem 1: 4 characters
    Subitem 2: 4 characters
    Subitem 3: 6 characters
    4 subitems
Item 2
    Subitem 0: 3 characters
    Subitem 1: 2 characters
    Subitem 2: 2 characters
    3 subitems
```

`data` can be also declared as

```
char *data[][4] = {{"gsga","baf"},{"ad","aasb","asdf","asdfsd"},{"ads","sd","sd"}};
```

But then you need to check for `NULL`'s to get the number of (non empty) subitems:

```
    for (iter2 = 0; iter2 < items2; iter2++) {
        if (data[iter1][iter2] != NULL) {
            len = strlen(data[iter1][iter2]);
            ...
        }
    }
```

[Full Code](https://ideone.com/aLD9Ho)

Comment: No problem ;), but I am curious, how to check the stack with valgrind?

Comment: *SGCheck: an experimental stack and global array overrun detector*: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/sg-manual.html

Answer (score 0):

The following program prints the values you mention:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LEN(arr) ((int) (sizeof (arr) / sizeof (arr)[0]))

int main(void)
{
    const char *A[][4] = {{"gsga", "baf"}, {"ad", "aasb", "asdf", "asdfsd"}, {"ads", "sd", "sd"}};

    printf("%d\n", LEN(A)); /*number of rows*/
    printf("%d\n", LEN(A[0])); /*number of columns*/
    printf("%d\n", (int) strlen(A[1][1]) + 1); /*size of element*/
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nitpicking: The `%d` is not nice.

Comment: @alk What do you suggest for ANSI C89?

Comment: At least an unsigned type. But why C89 at all?

Comment: Also the code does not take into account that there might "strings" larger then `A[1][1]`.

Comment: @alk Of course there might be strings larger than A[1][1], what was asked for was "the size of individual strings".

Comment: @alk A program written in C89 can be compiled on just about any computer.

Comment: The question is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: @alk I now cast size_t to int which works unless the arrays are huge.